# jQuery plugin is not working on my rails 3 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Am sorry if this has been already ask before, I tried searching but I couldn't find any solution..can somebody please help me get my jQuery plugin work in rails 3.

I have downloaded a jquery plugin in the internet, tried installing it on my rails app, it seems to be not loading at all..

Am sure I have placed all the necessary files needed for this plugin to work in assets/images, stylesheets, and javascripts

Here is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

and my gallery.js.coffee where it is suppose to be calling the plugin

```
jQuery ->
   $('#da-slider').cslider
```

and the partial that wraps the layout

```
<div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
```

I even tried testing if my plugin is working by asking it on my gallery.js.coffee, but it keeps saying 'not loaded'

```
if (jQuery).cslider 
  alert('loaded')
else
  alert('not loaded')
```

Thank you so much for the very kind help. Sorry to trouble anyone.

Comment: Can you tell me what error you get when you load the page? You should be able to see this error in Safari->Dev Console, or in Firefox using FireBug

Comment: Another thing to check would be that you have specified the `jquery-rails` and `coffee` gems in your Gemfile - downloading the jquery plugin from the internet is not enough if your application is not aware that you want to use it. You could also try moving the JS files from the downloaded plugin into your asset pipeline

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have `jquery-rails2.0.2` and `coffee-rails3.2.2` and theres no error or no issue at my safari console.. what could be wrong?

Comment: i have also moved the JS files to my asset pipeline..

Comment: Hmm if there is no error, I am wondering if the javascript is working, and you don't have to CSS files so it can't render it properly? What does your application.css file look like?

Comment: Also a thing to check, are you including application.css and application.js in your views? You should have something like the following in your `<html><head>` element:  `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'%>`  and  `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

Comment: i'm quite puzzled with this, all of my JS and css files are moved to `asset/css` and `asset/js`.

and my `application.css`
    *= require_self
    *= require_tree .
`<head>` is
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>`

  `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Comment: I posted what I have mentioned so far in an answer, just cause these comments are getting really long - however, maybe try what I suggested about in application.css, require the `jquery.ui.slider.css` file specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check for:

- Check for a javascript error when you load the page - you should be able to see this error in Safari->Dev Console, or in Firefox using FireBug
- Make sure you have the jquery-rail and coffee gems in your Gemfile
- Check the `application.js` and `application.css` files - they are both needed and should look like this:

*app/assets/javascripts/application.js*

```
//= require jquery.js
//= require jquery_ujs.js
```

*app/assets/stylesheets/application.css*

```
*= require jquery.ui.all.css
```

However, note, I have had some issues using the jquery.ui.all.css file, and you might have more success, like me, specifying it like so:

```
*= require jquery.ui.core.css
*= require jquery.ui.slider.css
```

**Note** Since you are using cSlider - I am thinking you **need** the `jquery.ui.slider.css` file!! Make sure you are either requiring the jquery all, or at least the slider css file.

- Lastly, make sure you are including application.css and application.js in your views - without those includes, the application cannot know what you want it to do. This should look something like this in your `<html><head>` section:

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'%>`

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

Comment: hi, I've tried all you have suggested me, but to no avail. ive read the manuals, and checked it. but there seems to be something wrong with the plugin? i know am asking too much but in your kind time, can you please check this plugin? 
[Link to website](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/).

thank you very much for the help and time.. sorry for the trouble. good day!

Comment: i dont know what happened, few `rake assets:precompile` and restart server, then suddenly, it started working.. weird. 

thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ah, I think you are using a different slider plugin than I was thinking - so I am not too sure what the problem is. However, I can offer this comment as to your solution: `rake assets:precompile` will change all of your assets to be static, and serve them up through `public/assets`. Was this broken in production mode? I had completely assumed it was development mode, so my apologies for that. If your asset pipeline is on, the default behavior will require running `rake assets:precompile` for any assets to work in production.

Comment: If you are interested, there are ways to turn that requirement off

Comment: hi, i am in development mode. i test or try new plugins on a separate app. its kinda annoying and am not used to develop on things like views. am not familiar with `rake assets:precompile`. is there any other way to turn that off? like whenever i install new plugins or files? the app would recognized that right away.

Comment: btw, no apologies needed, you commented out your best. i thank you for that. have a nice day :D